# Unicode characters properly pulled from MySQL [PHP MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I am fetching the image filepath from my MySQL database, and everything worked fine until the name of the path has some unicode characters associated to it. For example, I am using this code to fetch the image filepath;

```
$sql = "SELECT images FROM agents";
$basePath = "http://localhost/img/";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $img = $row['images'];
    $actualPath = $basePath . $img;
    echo $actualPath;
}
```

For English alphabet pictures, it's okay, it turned out something like `http://localhost/img/selena.jpg` but if it's using unicode characters, it will be like `http://localhost/img/11_??.jpg` whereas the true filepath would be `http://localhost/img/11_副本.jpg`
How do I make that `副本` characters stay after it is pulled from MySQL rather than just becoming `??` symbol ?

EDIT: I used a prepared statement method, not the basic `mysqli_query()` command.

Comment: You have to check the character set in PHP and mysql and the file saved name.

Comment: is it display as `副本` in your db?

Comment: @Beginner yes it does.

Comment: @AfiqIzzat try `$actualPath = $basePath . htmlentities($img,  ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @Beginner, the result still remains the same, it outputs å¯æ¬ instead of 副本

Comment: @AfiqIzzat whats the result if you `var_dump($row);` also check the encoding of your column `images` if is `UTF-8`  if not change it `UTF-8`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored ; look for "question marks".

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET NAMES UTF8` before your query to handle Unicode characters.

```
mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES UTF8');

$sql = "SELECT images FROM agents";
$basePath = "http://localhost/img/";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $img = $row['images'];
   $actualPath = $basePath . $img;
   echo $actualPath;
}
```

Comment: Does it work the same if I used prepared statement ?

Comment: Now, it becomes `http://localhost/img/11_å¯æ¬.jpg`, I still want it to become `副本`

Comment: Can you post how this image link is stored in the DB?

Comment: I stored only the filepath of the image and call it on another server for the picture by just relaying the filepath (basepath + imgpath). The filename is 11_副本.jpg.

Comment: when you query through terminal or any tool, does your image value in the DB look exactly like `11_副本.jpg` ?

Comment: thanks! this solved about an hour of scratching my head.